# Esperar Respuestas para continuar Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

Quiero hacer este codigo con funciones. Con la data del Login ya lo logre y se loguea perfecto, el problema viene despues con 2 cuestiones:
La primera, donde dice `#Clonar` hay un cambio de URL y se ejecuta automaticamente una vez que hago el click para loguearme. Eso hace que no termine de loguearse por eso necesitaria una funcion que no sea `time.sleep()` sino una que espere a que el login termine o que cuando `"onevideo.aol.com/#/Campaigns"` sea la pagina donde me encuentro en selenium(luego del login ingresa a esa url) ahi se ejecute mi `driver.get("https://onevideo.aol.com/#/inventorysources")`.

Por otro lado, aca va mi segunda cuestion. Necesito tal como hice para el login hacer lo mismo con #Clonar, #Nombre tag, #Rate, #Floor. A que me refiero con 'Lo mismo', es que para ir ejecutando cada paso hasta que no obtenga la respuesta no ejecute el siguiente

Gracias

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://onevideo.aol.com/#/")
timeout = 30

def login():
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-valid:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ng-valid:nth-child(1)")
    username.send_keys("martinbouhier")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn:nth-child(2)").click()
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.group-field-block:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.group-field-block:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")
    password.send_keys("pass")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button").click()

#Clonar
driver.get("https://onevideo.aol.com/#/inventorysources")
clone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.ngRow:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > adap-options-menu:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(2)').click()
clone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.open > ul:nth-child(5) > li:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)').click()

#Nombre tag
name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.margin-top-medium > input:nth-child(1)')
name.clear()
name.send_keys('--test$2--')

#Rate
Rate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.span9 > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1) > adap-input:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(2)')
Rate.clear()
Rate.send_keys('2')

#Floor
Floor = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.span9 > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(12) > div:nth-child(2) > adap-input:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)')
Floor.clear()
Floor.send_keys('2')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".bs-docs-social-buttons > li:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)").click()

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicar exactamente la misma idea a que en el login, usar una condición y un wait explicito.

Puedes usar `presence_of_element_located` con cualquier elemento de la pagina, de forma que se espere hasta que este este disponible. Hay mas condiciones, se pueden ver en la documentación de [`selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?highlight=expected).

El wait explicito, al contrario que uno implícito o lo que hace `time.sleep` (aunque este es bloqueante), se espera el tiempo que tu definas antes de lanzar una excepción pero en el momento en el que la  condición se cumple continua con la ejecución de forma inmediata (en vez de esperarse el *timeout* completo).

Lo que puedes hacer es escoger algún elemento de la pagina  `onevideo.aol.com/#/Campaigns`(un input, un botón , texto del final de la pagina, etc), y hacer un wait explicito usándolo. Esto lo haces al final de tu función `login`(después de que se pulse el botón), de forma que no retornara hasta que este elemento este presente y, por tanto, la pagina este cargada.

```
def login():
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-valid:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ng-valid:nth-child(1)")
    username.send_keys("martinbouhier")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn:nth-child(2)").click()
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.group-field-block:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.group-field-block:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")
    password.send_keys("pass")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button").click()


    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((tiposelector, selector))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```

Cambiando *tiposelector* y *selector*  por las variables adecuadas, buscando un elemento de la pagina que carga tras el login.

Puedes especificar el tiempo de espera que desees, si es negativo el tiempo de espera sera infinito.

Después de que la pagina sea cargada login retornara (o se lanza una excepción si el tiempo se excede) y puedes continuar con el resto (*clone*). El resto de código lo puedes meter en funciones y llamarlas una detrás de otras. Aparentemente te limitas a introducir texto en inputs por lo que en teoría no necesitas mas waits, no obstante la idea es la misma donde sea que lo necesites.

Comment: Ahi respondi mi pregunta con los cambios de mis funciones. Esta andando bien de esta forma pero me gustaria que me digas cualquier error que veas y ademas lo que dice sobre los time.sleep! Gracias

Comment: @MartinBouhier lo has resulto ya? No te puedo dar la respuesta concreta al no tener acceso a la pagina, pero la idea es esa, las dos ultimas lineas del código que muestro. Simplemente es esperar hasta que un elemento que tu quieras de la pagina a la que redirige el login este disponible antes de retornar. Así te aseguras que antes de que termine la función login `onevideo.aol.com/#/Campaigns` este cargada (y por tanto el login completado)

Comment: SIsi todo resuelto! Muchas gracias por la ayuda!